# Fourier series representation of piecewise function

Tags: fourier-series

$${Expand} \; f(x)= \begin{cases} 
      2{A\over L}x & 0\leq x\leq {L\over 2} \\
      \\
      2{A\over L}\left(L-x\right) & {L\over 2}\leq x\leq L 
   \end{cases}
$$

I have determined $A_0$ (but omitted) to be $A_0=A$. For $\ A_n \ $
 and $\ B_n$, I'm rather confused where to start. For $A_n$:
$$A_n={2\over L}\left[2{A\over L}\int_{0}^{L\over 2}x\cos\left({2n\pi x}\over L\right)dx+2{A\over L}\left(L\int_{L\over 2}^L\cos\left({2n\pi x}\over L\right)dx-\int_{L\over 2}^Lx\cos\left({2n\pi x}\over L\right)dx\right)\right]$$
And a similar case to $ B_n$, I'm not quite sure if I'm on the right path.

Comment: You are doing fine. The integration of $x\cos(\alpha x)$ can be done using integration by parts $f=x$ and $g'=\cos(\alpha x)$

Comment: Why $\cos\dfrac{2n\pi x}{L}$. Shouldn't be $\dfrac{n\pi x}{L}$?

Comment: Because for my case, my period is $L$ and so half of that would be $L\over 2$ which would be placed inside $\cos$ and $\sin$.

Answer (score 1):

That looks correct for $A_n$, you'll just need to evaluate some of the integrals by parts from here. For $B_n$, note that the function is even, and so $B_n = 0$ for all $n$, since they are coefficients of $\sin$ which is odd.

Comment: Even function means $f(-x)=f(x)$. But I fon't see the function defined in the negative domain. How much is $f(-L/4)$?

Comment: Are you referring to both cases of  the function $f(x)$ as being even? But wouldn't $A_n$ also be 0? By integrating $\cos\left({2n\pi x}\over L\right)$, the answer would yield 0 for the upper and lower boundaries for both cases because of $n\pi$? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Fourier series is defined on periodic functions. Assuming you're using period $L$, the function is even. Also, the answer would not yield 0; the $x\cos \left( \frac{2\pi n x}{L} \right)$ terms will not yield 0.